# Python regex ignorecase not working

Tags: python, regex

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

regex = re.compile('B', re.IGNORECASE)
print regex.match('abc')
```

returns None, when it should match.  I'm trying to use a regex 'B' and a search string of 'abc' with ignore case

Comment: Try this in an interactive session: `>>> help(re.match)`. Also try `>>> help(re.search)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match from the *beginning* of your input string.

It seems that you want [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), which *scans* the input string looking for a match.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('B', re.IGNORECASE)
m = regex.search('abc')
if m:
    print m.group(0)
```

Output:

```
b
```